# Generate docker image by maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, docker, tomcat

I have manually written dockerfile but now I need configure maven to create that file and build image. I'm trying do it with spotify's maven plugin.

Here is dockerfile which is written by me and it works:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8
RUN rm -rvf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY ./context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY /target/brainis-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I need ensure my maven plugin generate same docker file before build image. Can you tell me please how to achieve it? My current configuration generates only first command `FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8`, how to configure rest of that file in maven?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>spring-tomcat</imageName>
        <baseImage>tomcat:8.0-jre8</baseImage>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your `Dockerfile` to your codebase, i.e. `/src/main/docker/Dockerfile` and reference it from Spotify's Maven plugin this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
        <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The last part, resources, places the docker build base path in whichever folder you want it, i.e. `/target` and which files to include.

That will run your whole `Dockerfile` script

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I hoped this docker file will generated by maven plugin without reference to mine. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know a way, but personal recommendation is to have your own Dockerfile and control the specifics rather than relying on that plugin. AFAIK it will only run a Docker script or build from a parent docker image.

Comment: Ok, I tried your answer and give me that exception:
Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax
.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refu
sed: connect -> [Help 1]

:/

Comment: Check docker machine / docker for Windows/Mac is running on your computer. Looks like docker service is down.

Comment: I checked it and it looks it is running.